# Why some applications base 64 encode HMACs?

Tags: base64, hmac

Why some applications base 64 encode HMACs even if it's not for mail purposes?
Is it a vestige from older implementations or practices?

If you do a little research in google with the words 'HMAC', 'base' and '64' you will see many people do it, and i don't know why. I'm pretty sure that it has nothing to do neither with storing nor outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send binary data encoded into SOAP envelope or as JSON data, you would risk that the part of the raw data is interpreted as the structural elements of these formats (e.g. '<', '[', '{').

Therefore you need to encode it as Base64 to preserve its contents on the wire.